# Printing count of a column based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

| Dept_Name | Placed |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 1 |

Where 'Placed' column has a boolean value
I want to print the count of rows that have the value '1' in placed grouped by the Dept_Name

| Dept_Name | Count(Placed == 1) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are `0,1` or `True/False` you can aggregate `sum`, last for column `Count` use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Dept_Name')['Placed'].sum().reset_index(name='Count')
```

If test some non boolean values - e.g. count values `100`:

```
df2 = df['Placed'].eq(100).groupby(df['Dept_Name']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but a follow up. How would I proceed if the column was not boolean? Say, it had values such as "Placed in ABC", "Placed in XYZ" and I only needed count of rows for Dept_Name with Placed column value 'Placed in XYZ'

Comment: @Graleon3 - what values are in column?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a boolean 0/1 a simple sum will work:

```
out = df.groupby('Dept_Name', as_index=False).sum()
```

output:

```
  Dept_Name  Placed
0         A       5
1         B       0
2         C       2
```

For a named column:

```
out = df.groupby('Dept_Name', as_index=False).agg(**{'Count': ('Placed', 'sum')})
```

output:

```
  Dept_Name  Count
0         A      5
1         B      0
2         C      2
```